# how to count different keys with conditions in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dicts looks like this: they have different keys in the dicts

```
my_dicts = [
    {"id": "1","fixVersion": "1.2.3","releaseDate": "2017-01-21"},
    {"id": "2","fixVersion": "2.0", "releaseDate": "2023-01-21"},
    {"id": "3","fixVersion": "2.1", "releaseDate": "2023-07-01"},
    {"id": "84","changeRequests":"123"}
]
```

I want to count the id if there is "releaseDate" as the key in the dictionaries and also the date is after 2023-01-01.

so the final result should be 2 for this example

```
2
```

**any help is really appreciated!!**

Comment: And what have you tried?  You have practically written the program in pseudocode there.

Comment: You can achieve this with a simple loop and condition statement.

Comment: @TimRoberts I tried to use "in" to check if the key exist but it doesnot work, it always print 0 to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get()` function, that provides safe extraction from the dict. You can define what do you want to get as a result, if there's no such key in a dict (it's `None` by default).
For your case it would look like this:

```
filtered_dicts = [
    single_dict
    for single_dict in my_dicts
    if single_dict.get("releaseDate", "") >= "2023-01-01"
]
```

This will give you the list of dicts that satisfy your condition. If you want to count them only, you can do a one-liner with throwing in `len()` function.

```
len(
    [
        single_dict
        for single_dict in my_dicts
        if single_dict.get("releaseDate", "") >= "2023-01-01"
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 3):

It's just a matter of translating your words into Python code:

```
c = sum('releaseDate' in md and md['releaseDate'] >= '2023-01-01' for md in my_dicts)
```

although you could even simplify it to:

```
c = sum(md.get('releaseDate', '0000-00-00') >= '2023-01-01' for md in my_dicts)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use .get() to check for presence and compare values in a comprehension:

```
sum(d.get("releaseDate","")>"2023-01-01" for d in my_dicts) # 2
```